# how to normalize the records? e.g. several similar columns into rows

Tags: normalization, transformation, etl, pentaho, kettle

I am using Pentaho Kettle and thinking on way to normalize my flat file (csv) data. Eventually store it to database.

csv structure: item name, **store1 sold quantity, store2 sold quantity, store...**

expected result: item name, **store name, sold quantity**

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `Row Normalizer` step as long as the number of stores is fixed or at least has a maximum. If it's variable, you'll have to use a JavaScript step, or a UDJC. See the docs for how to use these steps:

[PDI Transform Steps](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+Steps)

If it's variable, I'd consider preprocessing the file before loading. I've done this with Python and it works pretty well.

Comment: perfrect by using Row Normalizer. Thanks.